# Text not being underlined in internet app on S4

Tags: browser, input-methods, text-input, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have an issue with my S4 browser:

1. Open Google site using the default Internet app (not Chrome)
2. Enable predictive text, input about 8 dots and then add some following characters
3. Notice that the line under the text would be placed incorrectly, like this: "........text __" (it must be the "text" with the correct underline)

I have checked with Chrome, and everthing seemed fine. I know that there must be something wrong with Webkit engine, but I can not find where it is, or even what class the issue comes from.

Could you please share some experiences for me? I appreciate your help.

B.R, Giap.